# How to use the recursive function in ros2

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I have a while loop that gets triggered when a msg is received on a topic. So while it's looping in while loop my node is not receiving any msg from any other topics. so that my looping can work updated data.
FYI when I mean a while loop I am using recursive function.

Let me know if you want any sample code or demo code for it.

Thanks for your help,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/397094/how-to-use-the-recursive-function-in-ros2/) by [Flash](https://answers.ros.org/users/67657/flash/) on ROS Answers with karma: 126 on 2022-03-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I used the [threading](https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/) function in python to solve the problem with the recursive function not sure if there was any better way to do that.

---

Originally posted by [Flash](https://answers.ros.org/users/67657/flash/) with karma: 126 on 2022-03-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0